# How to make PhpStorm add an import for root classes?

Tags: phpstorm

When I start typing a class name, and select a class from the dropdown, PhpStorm uses the short class name and automatically adds an import at the top of the file, which is very handy:

[image]

However, when I do the same for a root class, PhpStorm uses the FQCN, prepending `\` to the class name, and adding no import statement at the top of the file:

[image]

**Is there a way to configure PhpStorm to always use the short class name for root classes too?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use appropriate option for `Class` drop-down box under `PHP | Treat symbols from the global space` section: make sure it's "prefer import" instead of "prefer FQN".

That option is located at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import`

[image]

Comment: Works superbly. Thanks!